# CloudKit Server Rejected Request: Unknown field recordName

Tags: cloudkit, ckquery

I am doing a `CKQuery` like this in Swift 4:

```
CKQuery(recordType: package.recordType, predicate: 
  NSPredicate(format: "NOT (recordName IN %@)", package.recordNames as CVarArg))
```

...and I'm getting this `CKError`:

> CKError(_nsError: CKError 0x60000024dce0: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2000); server message = "Unknown field 'recordName'"; uuid = BCD7C8DA-04B0-4422-8A24-F6479D234706; container ID = "...")

Is there a special key to use when querying against the `recordName`?

Answer (score 1):

After digging some more, I discovered that you cannot query by the `recordName` directly, but you can query by the `recordID`. So instead of comparing an array of strings, you have to build an array of `CKRecordID`s and query like this:

```
//- 1 - Build an array of CKRecordIDs
package.recordIDs = [CKRecordID(recordName: "..."), CKRecordID(recordName: "...")]

//- 2 - Set the predicate to use the `recordID` key
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (recordID IN %@)", package.recordIDs as CVarArg)

//- 3 - Set the query and drop your mic
CKQuery(recordType: package.recordType, predicate: pred)
```

I hope that helps someone else.